# DRF: Is two sided object creation and relation assignment possible?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For example, I have two models,

1. Questionnaire Model
2. Profile Model
   These two models are linked by a one-to-one relation, where the one-to-one-field is declared on the questionnaire model.

I want to be able to:

1. Create a new questionnaire instance, and assign an existing profile instance to it
2. Create a new profile instance, and assign an existing questionnaire instance to it

Currently, because my one-to-one relation is defined on the questionnaire model, I can do 1)
However, I am not able to achieve 2)
How do i get both 1) and 2) working?

**Serializer**

```py
class ProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"
```

**Models**

```py
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    distance = models.FloatField(null=True)
    profile = models.OneToOneField("Profile", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="questionnaire", blank=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

**Views**

```py
class ProfileCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

**POST Request**

```json
{
    "bio": "I like to eat pizza",
    "questionnaire": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED with kind help from awesome people on Django Discord!

```py
class ProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    questionnaire_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        questionnaire_id = validated_data.pop("questionnaire_id")
        print(questionnaire_id)
        profile = super().create(validated_data)
        questionnaire = Questionnaire.objects.get(pk=questionnaire_id)
        questionnaire.profile = profile
        questionnaire.save()
        return profile
```